# Mocking a default backend independent of type and adress of call

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I want to test a service that has lots of API calls to an external API. I want to mock this backend without having to specify the adress the call should be made to. 
Whenever a GET is made I want `{test:true}` to be returned.

What I have right now requires me to specify the specific adress which does not work since the adress will change and there is no way for me to know to which adress the GET request will be made. Im using Karma with Jasmine on node-webkit.

```
authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', $rootScope.url)
.respond({test: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  regular expression:

```
authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/)
.respond({test: true});
```

`$httpBackend.when`'s accepts either a string or a Regexp object.